# Swift / SpriteKit - Can't break strong reference cycle

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, automatic-ref-counting

I completed a spritekit game without having knowledge of strong reference cycles.  I'm not having any crashes or obvious problems, but using instruments I can see my objects being retained between each level (SKScene should be dealloced between levels).

Here are the general pieces of my game:

**`GameConfig` static struct**

I have a globally accessible static struct that references my ViewController.  I access the viewController using this struct from all over the app.  I assign `GameConfig.viewController = self` inside of the viewController's `viewDidLoad`

**`GameViewController`**

In here I reference my SKScene, and SKView as such

```
var skView: MyView!
weak var scene: SKScene!
```

**`BaseScene`**

This is my base SKScene class.  This is the only property of this class that gets a reference to the class itself

```
let indicators: Indicators = Indicators()
```

**`KillScene` subclass of `BaseScene`**

In my BaseScene subclass, I have many custom subclasses contained in arrays.  These custom subclasses do reference the scene, but the scene is not referencing them directly.  It only has reference to their container array.  Example:

```
var radarBlips: [RadarBlip] = []
```

I do have one property that has a strong reference cycle with `KillScene`

```
var ship: KillShip = KillShip()
```

In both my `Indicators` and `KillShip` classes, I have referenced my scene using the `weak` keyword.

In fact I have found every instance where I reference the scene, and put `weak` in front of it.

I tried to make a stripped down game, and create a strong reference cycle between a sprite and a scene, and then break it.  I was successful in doing so.  But I can't seem to debug my own game.

Any detailed suggestions would be helpful.  I know there's trickiness with passing closures around.  Maybe that has something to do with it?  Any advice on what I could look for would be great.  I've put `weak` in more places than I probably need to.

I can not get the scene to `deinit`

Comment: When I've had strong reference cycles using sprite-kit it's either been because I forgot to add `weak` to a node that kept a reference to it's parent node. Or, I'd created a strong reference cycle by not using `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` in closures.

Comment: can you expand on the closures.  I haven't really looked into that.  Maybe link me a good reference?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blog.xebia.com/2014/10/09/function-references-in-swift-and-retain-cycles/ Then I'd recommend going through any closures you've created and making sure you're not creating any strong reference cycles.

Comment: i tried to brute force it.  i found every use of a closure in my game and modified them to use [weak self]..  no change.  any other ideas?  =/

Comment: What I would do is strip my code right back (just comment the scenes out), then keep adding bits of code back in until `deinit` isn't called. I'm afraid I can't help much past that without seeing any code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't an easy way to do this.  Check all your properties that reference eachother and use weak or unowned.  The bigger issue in spritekit is checking for closures.  When you're running delayed closures (in SKActions) and things like that it's important to use `[weak self]` within the closure so it doesnt keep the object alive.  It's easier to add more weaks and unowned than necessary until the strong reference cycle is broken and then work your way backwards deleting unnecessary ones.